# WPF: how to enable slider with jump of 0.1 and not complete number

Tags: wpf, slider

This is my `Slider`

```
<Slider Name="SliderSpeed"
        Minimum="0"
        Maximum="50"
        SmallChange="0.1" 
        LargeChange="1"
        IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
        TickPlacement="None"
        materialDesign:ThemeAssist.Theme="Dark"                          
        Value="{Binding Path=(properties:Settings.Default).Speed}"/>
```

So currently every time i move the `slider` the jump is 1 and i want the `value` to be able to be for example `1.5`

Also `properties:Settings.Default).Speed`defined as double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"`, also set the `TickFrequency` property:

```
<Slider x:Name="SliderSpeed"
        Minimum="0"
        Maximum="50"
        LargeChange="1"
        SmallChange="0.1" 
        TickFrequency="0.1"
        IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
        TickPlacement="None"
        materialDesign:ThemeAssist.Theme="Dark"                          
        Value="{Binding Path=(properties:Settings.Default).Speed}"/>
```